# How to properly split string array using C#

Tags: c#, php, json, json.net

I have a simple php script that outputs an array of strings using the  json_encode method at the backend. it outputs it like so:

```
["8090123","8090456","8090789","8090321","8090654"]
```

Now, I want to parse it in my C# code but I can't seem to parse it properly.

Below is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string myString = wc.DownloadString("https://magforex.biz/list.php");
                string[] words = myString.Split(',');
                for (var i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                {
                    // i just hardcoded the index for now
                    Console.WriteLine(words[0]); 
                    break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs just fine but it outputs the following result `["8090123"` which is not what I wanted.

Sorry as I am just starting out with C# and has limited knowledge about it.

All I want is just the string `8090123` so that I can do a comparison later.

Thanks for helping out in advance.

Comment: Use a JSON library like [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Comment: Use a JSON library, you don't want to parse it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a proper **JSON-parsing library** like [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the JSON string into a statically typed class model:

```
string[] words = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(myString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing one step:

```
string[] words = myString.Trim(new []{'[',']'}).Split(',');
```

Honestly, unless you're going to use `JsonConvert` for more complex object graphs, using a json deserializer is a bit of an overkill in this situation, IMHO.

EDIT: if you don't want the quotation marks, you could use a LINQ projection...

```
string[] words = myString.Trim(new []{'[',']'})
                     .Split(',')
                     .Select(s => s.Trim(new[]{'"'}).ToArray();
```

BTW, I'm highly familiar with Json.NET and have been a ServiceStack guy for ages. But I'm biasing towards the simpler solution because, well, [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), right?

Comment: you might be right. its just a simple array that i want to parse so I thought by just using the split method will do the trick. but the json library as suggested worked for my immediate need. I 'm not sure if its the right one for my simple task.

Comment: You were just missing the `Trim` step to cleanse the data prior to splitting...  ;-)

Comment: This method would still leave the quotes around the individual strings, so you would need a loop to strip those off too.  Using a JSON parser is a better way to go.

Comment: Just trim out what you don't want.. I thought they wanted the quote marks, TBH...

Comment: You'd have to trim the quotes *after* splitting values, otherwise only the first and last quote in the full string would be removed.  Something like `string[] words = myString.Trim(new char[]{'[',']'}).Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim(new char[]{'"'})).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the obvious thing and JSON-decode your JSON input data? Using Newtonsoft.Json:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(myString)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Newtonsoft library you can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to convert your string to array. Add `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` and then:

```
string myString = wc.DownloadString("https://magforex.biz/list.php");
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string[] myArray = js.Deserialize<string[]>(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change it to word[i] to start, then I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes I know. I just hardcode the index for now so I can prove if I am parsing the correct index or not before I run the loop. thanks ;)

Comment: then you probably want words.Join()

Comment: its ok. the json library as suggested by others worked! thanks anyway ;)